# Predictability of the mild solution of a SPDE

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the following theorem (picture below) taken from Pardoux's lecture notes: Stochastic partial differential equations available at scholar google: https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=etienne+pardoux+lecture+note+stochastic+partial+differential+equations&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart#d=gs_qabs&t=1674356056002&u=%23p%3DE86Iye_EWKsJ

For the existence he's using Picard iteration to provide a proof.

I have questions: supposing that $u_0$ is predictable ($\mathcal{P} \otimes \mathcal{B}([0,1])$-measurable) how can we prove by induction that $u_n$ is predictable? Also how to deduce that its limit $u$ is predictable? Why $\int_0^1p(t,x,y)u_0(y)dy$ is well defined and predictable?
[image]
[image]

Comment: the $u_{n}$ is defined in terms of integrals up to time $t$ so yes they are adapted to the filtration.

Comment: Why are they predictable?

Comment: because they are also continuous as integrals (any left-continuous adapted is predictable) and u0 assumed to be predictable. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352907/why-can-all-adapted-left-continuous-stochastic-processes-be-adapted-processes

Comment: Here predictable means $\mathcal{P} \otimes \mathcal{B}([0,1])$-measurable used in SPDE, not the one used in Ito integral

Comment: sure and as they mention in those notes, the filtration they consider is with respect to time t.